# Django doesn't show image with debug True

Tags: python, django

With these settings, django shows the file 404.png stored in static directory of the app `NeoRecApp` of the project `NeoRec` if `DEBUG=True`, otherwise it doesn't show if debug is set to false.

(After setting `STATIC_ROOT` I ran `python manage.py collectstatic`, which moved the file to the newly created 'NeoRecApp/static'.)

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False
#DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'NeoRecApp/static/'
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'NeoRecApp',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: try to access the image using `NeoRecApp/static/404.png`. I generally include `NeoRecApp/static` to the `STATICFILES_DIRS`  setting and keep my `STATIC_URL` to be `/static/` . Works fine for me (I removed `static.root` after running `collectstatic`

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns 404, which is my custom page, devoid of the image.

Comment: Same resukt. Only NeoRecApp gets added ahead of /static. The complete src path is "NeoRecApp/static/404.png". Also, it's hyperlinked to "http://localhost:8000/NeoRecApp/static/404.png". I haven't declared any urlpattern to NeoRecApp/* . But I don't see how that could help.

Answer (score 2):

I found out after reading more on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) that DEBUG flag is set to run Django's test server. Hence, if DEBUG=False, then static files won't be served by Django's `manage.py runserver` solution, and we have two options thereafter-

1. Deploy on a different server (Apache, Nginx,etc)
2. Use this module ([White noise](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whitenoise)) for serving static files.